# Using C#, how can I read the content of dynamic created textboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, dynamic-data

Hy,

I have created some dynamic textboxes with standard content.

Does anyone know how can I read the content of these textboxes (assuming that user modified the standard content) when I press one button?

Thanks a lot.

Jeff

**Update**

This is how I am creating the textboxes:

```
foreach (string name in listOfNames)
{
   TextBox tb = new TextBox();
   tb.Text = name;
   tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
   tb.BorderWidth = 0;
   tb.Font.Name = "Arial";
   tb.Font.Size = 8;
}
```

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, Silverlight, XNA, Windows Phone 7, XBox 360, Zune, ...???? Try to be a little more specific, there are textboxes and buttons everywhere. Also define *dynamic*. How are those textboxes created, ideally provide a code snippet.

Comment: What technology are you using? ASP.NET? Win-Forms? WPF/Silverlight?

Comment: In Addition to Darin's comment, how where they added?  DO you know the names?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET, I have updated the tags, sorry

Comment: @Jeff, tags are OK, now, the next part is the code snippet you had to provide about how are those textboxes created.

Comment: You don't seem to be adding the controls to the page at all. How are they added? To what controls collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific will vary depending on the technology you are using. However the concept would remain very similar, though for ASP.NET it will be a little more interesting.

**WinForms/WPF/Silverlight**

Maintain a list of the dynamically created textboxes and when the button is pressed you can run through the list of textboxes and read the `Text` property to get the user input.

**ASP.NET** - After the tag update it seems this section is most appropriate to your requirement.

For ASP.NET you will need to create the textboxes in an override of the OnInit method, this should happen on each postback. Then in the `Button.Click` event you can read the user input from the textboxes that you created in the OnInit function. You need to ensure that the controls are created with the same `ID` on each post back.

Comment: +1 - for "Same ID"...without a consistent ID, dynamic controls will render but all sorts of problems occur (like events that only fire when you click the element twice).

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that the text boxes are *recreated* on every postback.

If you do not recreate them, you will not be able to access their properties or events.

The best place to create dynamic controls is the page `Init` event handler.

I suggest reading up on the [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

---

Update (following updated question)

Make sure to set an `ID` (and a different one, at that) for the text boxes, so you can refer to them later on.

I can't see where you are adding these controls to the page either.

Comment: @Richard Friend - I never did that, but then again, I could be wrong. Can you point me to any articles that say this?

Comment: I know creating in Init works, however a lot of controls rely on EnsureChildControls() which inturn looks at ChildControlsCreated which in turn calls CreateChildControls.  see http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx

Comment: @Richard Friend - He also says (almost the very start of the article) that the page Init event handler is the best place. Using `CreateChildControls` is used for addressing a specific issue with exceptions.

Comment: He does say that but the summary at the end states to use CreateChildControls. again this is an area which seems unclear, however ms states thats what its for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504193/when-must-i-use-asp-net-createchildcontrols

Answer (score 0):

Request.Form is a collection of Key-Value pairs that represents all of the data coming back from the ASP.NET request. If you access that you can get any value whether its control is specified in the ASPX code or dynamically created in the code behind file.

You can also get their values placed back in them automatically if you recreate them during the init part of the page lifecycle. If you do this, their values will be set when ASP.NET recreates the state of the page and applies the values from the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access them as you would a normal control, you just need to get a reference to the control.
Remember to re-create all controls on each postback.

[this](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx) is a useful article on dynamic controls in asp.net